# What's the reasoning for full-stop landings at night but touch-and-gos during the day for passenger currency?

Tags: faa-regulations, currency

FAR 61.57 says that you need to have completed three takeoffs and landings to a full stop in order to carry passengers at night. However, you only need three touch-and-gos in order to carry passengers during the day.

**Why the difference?**

Is there some rationale for this?  Are full-stop landings considered safer during the night?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are three really convincing arguments I've heard for this - I'm not sure which is "correct" and explains the FAA's logic, but personally I suspect it's a little bit of each.

---

**Argument 1:** Night landings are "special".

A night landing is definitely different from a day landing - there's much less of a sight picture in the flare unless your airport is in a really bright area or you have a bright moon (and even then it's "different").
If all you're doing is tapping your wheels on the ground and quickly accelerating back to takeoff speed you're missing a lot of what a landing is - bringing the nose down, decelerating to a safe taxi speed, and leaving the runway under control.

Which conveniently brings us to...

---

**Argument 2:** "You gotta learn how to taxi all over again!"

That's something my instructor told me, and I didn't really understand what he meant until I was in the plane. Airports are ***really dark*** and it's hard to find your way around the taxiways at night. Personally I think a big part of this requirement is the *intent* that you taxi off the runway and make your way back to the end to shoot another circuit. The hardest thing about my night training - aside from *finding the darn airports* was taxiing around without getting lost.

(Of course the regs don't say anything about "Taxi off the runway" - they just say "full stop". You can satisfy the legal requirement with "stop-and-go" landings, but there's a nagging voice in my head that says you're not really "getting current" if that's all you do...)

---

**Argument 3:** It slows your procedures down, which makes you safer.

Touch-and-Go landings are kinda dangerous if you think about them - *Bring the plane in for a landing (which is already a lot of work). Now as soon as all your wheels are on the ground make a mental judgment as to whether you have enough runway to take off from given your current position & rolling start, if so retract your flaps to an appropriate takeoff setting, cram the throttle back in, and take off again.*.
When you look at them that way it's a bit odd that we have students do them (and there's more than one CFI around on the internet who says it's a lousy teaching tool).

Adding "Oh yeah, and it's dark out!" to that already difficult and dangerous procedure above is just *begging* for an accident - especially in a retractable gear aircraft (gear lever, flaps lever, and what happens if you miss in the dark cockpit?).

Comment: It is also much more difficult to judge distance at night (i.e. runway remaining) and if you misjudge that, it could create a major problem!

Comment: @Lnafziger, your answer has my vote!

Comment: @Lnafziger absolutely - the only way I was comfortable doing stop-and-go landings in my training was if I could stop before our runway intersections (so I knew I had a good few thousand feet left). It's REALLY HARD to judge distance over the ground when all you have are the runway lights!

Comment: I like this answer, especially argument 2. I do agree that slowing down procedures does make you safer. I'm not really on the same page about touch-and-gos being all that more dangerous at night. Then again I do fly out of class D airport near the city with 4400ft of pavement (minus displaced thresholds but still) so it is pretty well lit and lots of room to play. Anyway I am pretty conservative though I'm the type of pilot that lines up at the VERY beginning of the runway, gets right on the centerline, holds the brakes till like 2k+ rpm checking for green, unless tower wants a no delay.